# Clearing a form after POST in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, post, webforms, postback

Whats the normal procedure of clearing a form after POST? Just loop through the textboxes and cleat all text? I have an ASP.NET application with several forms and I am trying to avoid them sending the data twice?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid double sending/doing by putting your code inside an if(!isPostBack) block.  This will tell the page not to do the specified actions when posting.

Comment: You are correct. That helped with the dual posting. If the users click a new page and then use the browser back button to go back to the form, can they do a re-post?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject some javascript code to execute after postback.

```
document.forms[0].reset();
document.forms[1].reset();
```

From server side, I haven't found an easy way to reset the form contents other than iterating through the controls inside a loop or doing a [Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=839521) back to the same page.